How do covectors and their basis work in Clifford/geometric algebra?
I'm curious about how covectors in linear algebra operate in Clifford/geometric algebra. So far, all the information I've come across regarding "dual vectors" seems to be connected to either the Hodge star operator or differential forms instead.
In my exploration of Clifford/geometric algebra materials, I've also encountered the concept of reciprocal basis. Is it equivalent to dual basis in linear algebra?

A Clifford algebra is constructed from a metric, and a (nondegenerate) metric is equivalent to an isomorphism $\flat : V\cong V^*$. In this sense there isn't really anything to be said, since you can always use the metric to translate a statement about covectors into a statement about vectors.
The reciprocal basis is not quite the same thing as the dual basis, but it is instead $\flat^{-1}$ applied to the dual basis.
See this answer of mine for what $\flat$—and hence the reciprocal basis—mean. See this one for how this extends to multivectors, but do note that the discussion is much simpler for nondegenerate Clifford algebras since we can essentially ignore $V^*$ and replace the Poincaré isomorphism with the Hodge star; and the Hodge star is represented simply by multlplying by a pseudoscalar.
